# git post-receive hook + defining environment variables

Tags: mysql, git, bash, environment-variables, hook

I am using a post-receive HOOK for Git deployment purposes? The goal is to set up the code so that deployment can take place with no issue. The problem that I have is that environment variables have to be defined properly or else things (like the database) will fail - like below.

How can I define the environment variables in a post-receive Hook for Git?

TIA

**post-receive file:**

```
[... snip ...]

if [ "prod" == "$branch" ]; then
    git --work-tree=$target_directory checkout -f prod
fi

CUR_TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
echo "$CUR_TIME CD to the target directory $target_directory and complete the actions" >> $LOGFILE
cd $target_directory

composer='which composer'

CUR_TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d:%H:%M:%S`
echo "$CUR_TIME Remove items from cache and view areas" >> $LOGFILE
rm -f storage/cache/*
echo "storage cache cleared for $target_directory"

rm -f storage/views/*
echo "storage views cleared for $target_directory"

#remove compiled cache files if they exist
rm -f bootstrap/compiled.php
rm -f app/storage/meta/services.json

# install packages, this also regenerates the autoloader
$composer install --no-scripts --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist
#$composer install

# Ensure that storage's folder have write permission for the group
chmod -R g+w storage

#fixing permissions for files that got disturbed along the way
chown -R $(users):$(users) .
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \; && find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# run any outstanding migrations
$php artisan migrate --force

# optimize autoloader and compile common classes
$php artisan optimize --force

$php artisan config:cache

$php artisan route:cache


[... snip ...]
```

**log (I get this error)**:

```
remote:   - Installing league/flysystem (1.0.35): Loading from cache
remote:   - Installing laravel/framework (v5.4.15): Loading from cache
remote:   - Installing laravel/tinker (v1.0.0): Loading from cache
remote: Generating autoload files
remote: Current application environment: production
remote:
remote:
remote:   [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
remote:   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using pa
remote:   ssword: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schem
remote:   a = forge and table_name = migrations)
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote:   [PDOException]
remote:   SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using pa
remote:   ssword: NO)
remote:
remote:
remote: Generating optimized class loader
remote: The compiled services file has been removed.
remote: Configuration cache cleared!
remote: Configuration cached successfully!
remote: Route cache cleared!
remote:
remote:
remote:   [LogicException]
remote:   Unable to prepare route [api/user] for serialization. Uses Closure.
remote:
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly your issue. Environment variables should be defined in `.env` file. This command for example `php artisan migrate --force` uses `.env` file to resolve db host/pass/user and others. There is no need to redefine those in git hook.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response :) I found that I was executing the items in the incorrect order. I followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNNHfl6vXQU&index=5&list=PLwAKR305CRO_WMJAJxGz6UCViQyAjdjgo and it resolved my issue. TIA